# Trying to combine three datatables from three HTML pages to one page

Tags: javascript, python, sql-server, flask, datatables

I am working on a webapp that will free up costly licenses for my employer's warehouse.

The warehouse staff can see who is assigned to an order as they come in (table 1), what stock items are on the orders (table 2) and where the stock items are (table 3). When you click on the 'RefNo' on table 1, it opens up table 2 on a new tab. When you click on the 'Stock Item' name on table 2, it opens up table 3 on a new tab. They all render perfectly on their given tabs.

The data in the three tables are coming from SQL Server through Python. Table 1 comes from a view and tables 2 and 3 come from stored procedures. I'm using Datatables for the tables themselves.

Below is the python script for the three tables in an app.py file

```
@/app.route('/pick-info', methods=['GET'])
@/login_required
def picks():
   cursor = cnxn.cursor()
   cursor.execute(select_picks)
   data = cursor.fetchall()
   return render_template('picks.html', data=data)


@/app.route('/pick-info/<int:PickRefNo>')
@/login_required
def picks_line(PickRefNo):
   cursor = cnxn.cursor()
   cursor.execute(pick_lines, (PickRefNo,))
   pick_data = cursor.fetchall()
   return render_template('picklines.html', pick_data=pick_data)


@/app.route('/pick-location/<int:StockItemRefNo>')
@/login_required
def pick_location(StockItemRefNo):
   cursor = cnxn.cursor()
   cursor.execute(pick_locations, (StockItemRefNo,))
   location_data = cursor.fetchall()
   return render_template('picklocations.html', location_data=location_data)
```

I have tried to combine the three pages into one with the following HTML file

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="pick-table po-table">
           <table id="pickexample" class="display table-responsive>
               <thead>
                  <tr style="text-align: center;">
                      <th>
                      </th>
                      <th scope="col" class="">
                           <button type="button" class="btn">
                              RefNo
                           </button>
                      </th>
                      <th scope="col" class="">
                           <button type="button" class="btn">
                              <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
                           </button>
                      </th>
                      <th scope="col" style="text-align: center; font-size: 10px;">
                            <button type="button" class="btn">
                               A/C
                            </button>
                      </th>
                      <th scope="col">
                            <button type="button" class="btn">
                               Due
                            </button>
                      </th>                               
                  </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  {% for value in data %}
                   <tr class="pick" style="text-align: center;">
                       <td class="details-control"></td>
                       <td><a class="text-white" href="{{url_for('picks_line',  PickRefNo = value[0])}}" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></a>{{ value[0] }}</td>
                       <td>{{ value[2] }}</td>
                       <td>{{ value[5] }}</td>
                       <td>{{ value[4] }}</td>                                
                   </tr>
                   {% endfor %}
               </tbody>
         </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px; height: 40vh;">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
         <table id="picklines" class="display table-responsive table">
               <thead>
                   <tr style="text-align: center;">
                      <th>
                      </th>
                      <th scope="col" class="">
                          <button type="button" class="btn">
                              Stock Item
                          </button>
                       </th>
                       <th scope="col" style="text-align: center; font-size: 10px;">
                          <button type="button" class="btn">
                              Name
                           </button>
                       </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                           <button type="button" class="btn">
                              Pick Qty
                           </button>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                           <button type="button" class="btn">
                                Picked Qty
                           </button>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                           <button type="button" class="btn">
                                To Be Picked
                            </button>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <button type="button">
                                 Weight
                             </button>
                         </th>
                    </tr>
             </thead>
              <tbody>
                 {% for value in pick_data %}
                 <tr class="pick" style="text-align: center;">
                     <td><a class="black-text" href="{{url_for('pick_location',  StockItemRefNo = value[2])}}" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-2x fa-info-circle"></i></a></td>
                     <td>{{ value[2] }}</td>
                     <td>{{ value[17] }}</td>
                     <td>{{ value[3] }}</td>
                     <td>{{ value[4] }}</td>
                     <td>{{ value[15] }}</td>
                     <td>{{ value[11] }}</td>
                 </tr>
                {% endfor %}
             </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4">
          <table id="picklocation" class="display table-responsive">
              <thead>
                  <tr style="text-align: center;">
                      <th scope="col" class="">
                         <button type="button" class="btn">
                           Zone
                         </button>
                      </th>
                      <th scope="col" style="text-align: center; font-size: 10px;">
                           <button type="button" class="btn">
                               Bin
                           </button>
                       </th>
                       <th scope="col">
                           <button type="button" class="btn">
                               Quantities
                            </button>
                       </th>
                       <th scope="col">
                           <button type="button" class="btn">
                              Pallet Number
                           </button>
                       </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for value in data %}
                      <tr class="pick" style="text-align: center;">
                         <td>{{ value[0] }}</td>
                         <td>{{ value[1] }}</td>
                         <td>{{ value[2] }}</td>
                         <td>{{ value[3] }}</td>
                      </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
     </div>
```

I've tried initialising all three tables in the JS at the top of the HTML file and used this blog post to help me along (https://datatables.net/blog/2017-03-31)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#pickexample').DataTable({
            dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-6 text-center'B><'col-sm-3'f>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
            buttons: [
                'colvis'
            ],
            fixedHeader: {
                header: true
            },            
            scrollY: 590,
            "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                if (data[5] == "InProgress") {
                    $(row).addClass('inprogress')
                } else {
                    $(row).addClass('newpick')
                }
            },
            iDisplayLength: -1,
            columnDefs: [
                { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 0 },
                { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 1 },
                { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 2 },
                { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 3 },
                { responsivePriority: 2, targets: 4 },
                { responsivePriority: 2, targets: 5 },
                { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 6 },
                { responsivePriority: 3, targets: 7 },
                { responsivePriority: 3, targets: 8 },
                { responsivePriority: 2, targets: 9 },
                { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 10 },
                { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 11 },
                { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 12 },
                { responsivePriority: 2, targets: 13 },
                { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 14 }
            ],

            responsive: {
                details: {
                    renderer: function (api, rowIdx) {
                        // Select hidden columns for the given row
                        var data = api.cells(rowIdx, ':hidden').eq(0).map(function (cell) {
                            var header = $(api.column(cell.column).header());

                            return '<tr>' +
                                '<td>' +
                                header.text() + ':' +
                                '</td> ' +
                                '<td>' +
                                api.cell(cell).data() +
                                '</td>' +
                                '</tr>';
                        }).toArray().join('');

                        return data ?
                            $('<table/>').append(data) :
                            false;
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });

    $('#pickexample tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });

    function format(rowData) {
        var tableUrl = "/";
        var div = $('<div/>')
            .addClass('loading')
            .text('Loading...');

        $.ajax({
            url: "tableUrl",
            data: {
                name: rowData.name
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                div
                    .html(json.html)
                    .removeClass('loading');
            }
        });

        return div;
    }

  
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#picklines').DataTable({
            dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-6 text-center'B><'col-sm-3'f>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
            buttons: [
                'colvis'
            ],
            fixedHeader: {
                header: true
            },
            scrollY: 550,
            paging: false,
            iDisplayLength: -1,
        })
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#picklocation').DataTable({
            dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-6 text-center'B><'col-sm-3'f>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
            buttons: [
                'colvis'
            ],
            fixedHeader: {
                header: true
            },
            scrollY: 590,
            iDisplayLength: -1,

        });


    function refreshPage() {
        window.location.reload();
    }
```

When I open this page, table 1 renders perfectly, table 2 and table 3 initialise but no data (which is what I'd expect) but it's the last jump to be able to click on a row on table 1, which passes the RefNo to the stored procedure to open table 2 and then to be able to click on the item name in table 2 to pass into the stored procedure for opening table 3. With table 2 (id=''picklines'') and table 3 (id=''picklocation'') coming from stored procedures - is there a way to get these to render based on the row I click?

I have asked a similar question on the Datatables forum and they have suggested using AJAX however the manuals for that do not show how to use AJAX with SQL stored procedures.

I should probably add that I am a junior developer and the only developer in the business so when I get stuck, I have no colleagues I can seek help from. If I am lacking detail in the question, I am happy to add more. Any advice or resources where I could learn how to do this, or the best ways to approach it - anything at all that points me in the right direction would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks

**Update**

```
@login_required
def picks():
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    data=cursor.execute(select_picks).fetchall()   
    return render_template('picks-orders.html', data=data)


@app.route('/picks/<int:PickRefNo>', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def picks_andlines(PickRefNo):
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    data=cursor.execute(select_picks).fetchall()   
    pick_data = cursor.execute(pick_lines, (PickRefNo,)).fetchall()
    return render_template('picks-andlines.html', data=data, pick_data=pick_data)


@app.route('/picks/<int:PickRefNo>/<int:StockItemRefNo>', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def pickslines_andlocations(PickRefNo, StockItemRefNo):
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    data=cursor.execute(select_picks).fetchall()   
    pick_data = cursor.execute(pick_lines, (PickRefNo,)).fetchall()
    location_data=cursor.execute(pick_locations, (StockItemRefNo,)).fetchall()
    return render_template('picks-all.html', data=data, pick_data=pick_data, location_data=location_data)
```

The answer you gave me allows me to load all three tables at the same time where I specify the PickRefNo and the StockItem in the address bar manually. I have tried to load table 1 by itself, then table 1 and 2 on the next page and then tables 1, 2 and 3 on the last page.
Not sure how the href to the last page should look - I have tried this

"{{url_for('pickslines_andlocations',  StockItemRefNo = value[2])}"

but I'm not sure how to include the current PickRefNo to that?

I might be going about this arseways, apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Just create one route for all tables, using PickRefNo and StockItemRefNo as route variables, like below:

```
@/app.route('/pick-info/<int:PickRefNo>/<int:StockItemRefNo>', methods=['GET'])
@/login_required
def picks(PickRefNo, StockItemRefNo):
   cursor = cnxn.cursor()
   data=cursor.execute(select_picks).fetchall()   
   pick_data = cursor.execute(pick_lines, (PickRefNo,)).fetchall()
   location_data=cursor.execute(pick_locations, (StockItemRefNo,)).fetchall()
return render_template('picks.html', data=data, pick_data=pick_data, location_data=location_data)
```

and add all three tables in picks.html

Comment: Thanks @IoaTzimas - 
That has been a huge help! I've made some progress. 
I get the following error -  Could not build url for endpoint 'pickslines_andlocations' with values ['StockItemRefNo']. Did you forget to specify values ['PickRefNo']
from the href on the second table that should open table 3. If I comment out that href, the page loads as expected.

Comment: You must adjust any urls to your route structure (with 2 variables. Are all your 3 tables loaded in the html file?

Comment: I'll add an edit to the bottom of the question to show you how it's looking now.